# Listening for the end of a song - jukebox

Tags: java, swing, javasound

I am making a jukebox program to run independently on a raspberry pi using netbeans.  I'm trying to write a method that allows for the music to switch after it has finished playing.  I know how to create a listener, but I need to still have the JPanel operations working.  As of now I have a button that will change a variable shuffle and I have the shuffle algorithm created.  I need to know how to create a thread that listens to see if the thread the audio is played on is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html).[`addLineListener(LineListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html#addLineListener-javax.sound.sampled.LineListener-).

> Instances of classes that implement the [`LineListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineListener.html) interface can register to **receive events when a line's status changes**.